# How to run an applet embedded in a HTML page using LTI CIVIL (DLL files) in NetBeans

Tags: java, applet, webcam

I'm developing an app in NetBeans 7.4 which uses  **Lti-Civil DLL files** for opening my webCam, I have to add to my project next parameter:

> Properties -> Run -> VM Options: ->
>   -Djava.library.path="lib/win32-x86" -Djava.security.policy=applet.policy

---

lib/win32-x86 = directory within my project which stores **Lti-Civil DLL files**
If I want to make the JAR file Running I do the following in terminal:

```
java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\myUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CapturaCamaraWeb2\lib\win32-x86" -Djava.security.policy=applet.policy -jar C:\Users\myUser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CapturaCamaraWeb2\dist\CapturaCamaraWeb2.jar
```

- I have to build this in a working applet (done)
- build a HTML File and embed the Applet (done)
- Make the applet work inside HTML file (not done yet)

---

**Applet**

[image]

---

**Web Applet error message on load**

[image]

---

**Web Applet:**

[image]

---

**Java Console**

[image]

---

**EDIT:** as far as I see this error message refers to this class 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the libraries directly to your projects' libraries/dependencies.

In Netbeans, right-click on Libraries and select `Add Jar/Folder` to add the dependent libraries.

Once this is done, you don't have to manually specify the path while running again.

In order to build the project, right-click on the project and select "Clean & Build" - it'll create a `dist` directory containing the build output files along with all dependencies within a lib folder.

If you want all dependencies to go directly into your jar, you can use Netbeans package-for-store option in `Run Target` under build.xml

Right-click on the build.xml in the Files pane. (Windows menu -> Files to see the Files pane)

[image]

Comment: 1. I zipped the folder with the .dll files, 2) added them as a Jar/Folder 3) clean and build project 4) java -jar myproject (in terminal) 5) the result is just the window without any picture, I'm going to upload my project in mediafire for making easier the support

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/k6eck0r9zlxrq2e/CapturaCamaraWeb2.zip <--- link to my project